# BlenderGIS not staying in an USB stick

Tags: blendergis

I was making a 3D map for school using the BlenderGIS addon, and put the done project in an USB stick, but the SRTM data doesn't stay there (it works on my PC, but not on other's(the SRTM data stays in my PC, not the USB)). What should I do?

P.S. If on a diffrent PC I press get SRTM data it gives me an error

Comment: "I press get SRTM data it gives me an error" what error?

Comment: @Mapperz It first gives me the screen to enter the API key, but when I do it says "unable to get SRTM data"